# How can i send a message to disconnected customers with spring kafka?

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I can not send messages to disconnected clients.
I use spring boot with apach kafka as a message broker.

Comment: If client is disconnected from Kafka, there is no way to reach it until it connects back. Fully unclear what is your goal ...

Comment: as facebook and linkedIn if you send a message to disconnected friend ,
your friend ,when he open his account he find your message , i would like to make application like that

Comment: That’s fine: you send to Kafka topic and it is stored there. When you user connects , he will use a stored offset to poll unread messages. That’s really just standard Kafka behavior. But this is not reflected in your question. That’s not how things work here. We have our job to do and we don’t play spy games if you would like some help from here

Comment: thank you friend , but how can i use a stored offset to poll unread message ?
here is my app : https://github.com/HassenBenSlima/MessageBroker-kafka/tree/feature2

Comment: That is done automatically by consumer when the same group is supplied. Please, read more about Apache Kafka

Answer (score 0):

If you assign a consumer group id to a user's inbox, then the consumer protocol will read from the last unread message automatically until you commit the consumed offset back to Kafka

Kafka persists messages itself and consumers are not required to be online to receive events sent immediately from producers